# jquery, display on hover text from a in p

Tags: jquery, clone, show

Sorry for dumb question but im very begginer in jquery. Mine code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Link 1</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Link 2</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Link 3</li>
</ul>

<p></p>

$("a").hover(function(){
    var ind = $(this).val();
    $("p").text(ind)
});
```

I would like to show on hover text from a in my paragraph. Probably its big piece of crap code. Help me please...

Answer (score 2):

use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Also you have text inside `li` , you can put it inside a

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    var ind = $(this).text();
    $("p").text(ind)
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/yKkzS/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    var ind = $(this).text();
    $("p").text(ind)
});
```

and fix your markup to include text inside anchor.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD4Sz/)

**from [doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns null.

Comment: Yeep, sorry for markup, that was my mistake. Problem with val/text solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PawełGrzybek you are welcome. See my answer update for the reason why val() did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are correct. Just wanted to point out that your html should probably look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<p></p>
```

Notice that the `<a>` tags wrap the text now.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put `li` text inside the anchor tags see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XXzDz/1/)

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and your jquery code should look like this one:

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $("p").text($(this).text());
});
```

Hope this helps.